# DNS and Subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

We're switching the DNS over to XX's servers for our website.

We have loads of subdomains and they have their own IP addresses. Will switching over our DNS affect our subdomains?

Comment: Subject and asking. When ppl learn asking questions smart.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that DNS is how all those subdomains get pointed to the correct IP address then yes switching your DNS provider for the main domain will affect them. However as long as you put all the appropriate settings for them on the new DNS servers then they shouldn't really notice the change.

Comment: thanks by appropriate settings you mean a/cname records?

Comment: Yes. You really just want to mirror the zone config from the old server to the new server.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how the responsibility of the zones are handled.

1. If all of your subdomains live inside a big honkng zone, change whatever IP needs changing and you are done.
2. If, however, some of the SD are delegated - i.e. they have a different administrator and therefore live in a different zone - you need to update the delegation(s) by changing the NS glue records and all that jazz.

I'd bet your situation is probably (1) - if you were a (2) you should already know it.

Remeber that you may need to update the reverse delegation also (i.e. the address => name mapping).

Cheers.

Comment: Probably all one giant zone.  If so, golden.  Domain in question would make this easier.